# HTML Forms don't work

Tags: html, forms

I've tried to create a form in HTML like:

```
<form method = "input" action=response.html method="post" >
  <p><label>Name:<input name="name" type="text" /></label><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </p>
</form>
```

This page works but when I click "Submit" It directs me to the response.html:

```
<html>
<head>    
<h3>name:</h3>    
</head>    
</html>
```

It doesn't return the name I typed in the  textbox. It just returned a big bold "name:" text in response.html. How come?

Comment: `method = "input"` isn't valid HTML

Comment: put quotes around "response.html"

Comment: I know it's not a huge deal, but all the spaces in the html are annoying the hell out of me

Comment: Why are you doing things more difficult? It's easier to just write "<html>" instead of "< html>".

Comment: They didn't know how to format the code. I've fixed that for them.

Comment: HTML isn't *technically* a programming language, without a server side script nothing will happen, and your page will just redirect to the given page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected. Your form action is set to `response.html` which means the form will submit the data to that page and unless you do something to prevent it, that page will be rendered in your browser.

If you want a different page to handle the form submission you need to set your form action to that URL and then redirect to `response.html`.

Additionally, your `repsonse.html` is invalid HTML. You need to put your content inside `<body></body>` tags. Not in your `<head>`.

Comment: The response.html still reports "name:". What should I do?

Comment: That's because you didn't write any code to output the submitted name. HTML alone cannot do that for you.

Comment: Oh, so do I have to use php to do it or could I do it in bare HTML?

Comment: You would need a server side language like PHP

Answer (score 3):

First off, `method="input"` is not a valid request method. Use `"GET"`, `"POST"` or perhaps other valid method.

Second, the `action` attribute tells the form where to send the request. This is exactly what happens - a request is sent to your html file. You need to process the request data first (e.g. using PHP) in order to actually insert in into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The method must be `GET` or `POST` and the code must be inside the `<body>` tag